# Vim Jedi Initalize

Tags: vim, autocomplete, jedi-vim

I was trying initalize jedi-vim. But i am getting "Not an editor command: Plugin 'davidhalter/jedi-vim'" error. I tried Plug , plug , Plugin , plugin but still getting the same error. README of jedi-vim repository says:

```
Add the following line in your ~/.vimrc    
Plugin 'davidhalter/jedi-vim'
```

this is .vimrc file:

```
Plugin 'davidhalter/jedi-vim'
let g:jedi#auto_initialization = 0
let g:jedi#auto_vim_configuration = 0
let g:jedi#use_tabs_not_buffers = 1
let g:jedi#use_splits_not_buffers = "left"
let g:jedi#popup_on_dot = 1
let g:jedi#popup_select_first = 0
let g:jedi#show_call_signatures = "1"
let g:jedi#goto_command = "<leader>d"
let g:jedi#goto_assignments_command = "<leader>g"
let g:jedi#goto_stubs_command = "<leader>s"
let g:jedi#goto_definitions_command = ""
let g:jedi#documentation_command = "K"
let g:jedi#usages_command = "<leader>n"
let g:jedi#completions_command = "<C-Space>"
let g:jedi#rename_command = "<leader>r"
let g:jedi#environment_path = "/usr/bin/python3.9"
let g:jedi#environment_path = "venv"
let g:jedi#completions_enabled = 0
```

and i have downloaded jedi-vim , if you think you haven't downloaded the jedi-vim.
**How can i solve this.**
i was tried with pathogen.
this is .vimrc

```
xecute pathogen#infect()
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on


let g:jedi#auto_initialization = 1
```

And i am getting Omni completion (^O^N^P) Pattern not found
error. I saw a question in stack overflow but i couldn't understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was trying initalize jedi-vim. But i am getting "Not an editor command: Plugin 'davidhalter/jedi-vim'" error. I tried Plug , plug , Plugin , plugin but still getting the same error

`Plug`, `plug` and `Plugin` are presumably commands for different Plugin managers that you most likely aren't using.

I might suggest you try using [vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug) as I found it relatively straightforward for a beginner to set up. From vim-plug's README, copy/paste and run the relevant shell command for your operating system and version of vim (If you're using Linux or Mac, it's `curl` command listed under `Unix`) and add the following to your .vimrc

```
" Specify a directory for plugins
" - For Neovim: stdpath('data') . '/plugged'
" - Avoid using standard Vim directory names like 'plugin'
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')

Plug 'davidhalter/jedi-vim'

" Initialize plugin system
call plug#end()
```

Resource your .vimrc (or just close and open vim again) and run `:PlugInstall` from vim command mode.